# How to Inject Stages or steps in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The output of this python eval looks like it could be stages in a jenkins pipeline

```
 $ python3 -c 'print("\n".join(["stage({val}) {{ do something with {val} }}".format(val=i) for i in range(3)]))'
stage(0) { do something with 0 }
stage(1) { do something with 1 }
stage(2) { do something with 2 }
```

Is it possible for jenkins to use output like this to **create** steps or stages in a pipeline so the running python script is able to update jenkins ? The point of this would be to have Blue Ocean pipeline have a stage dot that was made by an external script running separate jobs.

To elaborate on the example ... if this demo.py script which outputs the uptime in a stage

```
#!/bin/env python3.6
import subprocess, time

def uptime():
    return (subprocess.run('uptime', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf8')).stdout.strip()

for i in range(3):
    print("stage({val}) {{\n    echo \"{output}\" \n}}".format(val=i, output=uptime()))
    time.sleep(1)
```

where to be setup in a jenkins pipeline

```
node {
    stage("start demo"){
        sh "/tmp/demo.py"

    }
}
```

As is this demo just outputs the text and does not create any stages in blue ocean

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ /tmp/demo.py
stage(0) {
    echo "03:17:16 up 182 days, 12:17,  8 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.05" 
}
stage(1) {
    echo "03:17:17 up 182 days, 12:17,  8 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.05" 
}
stage(2) {
    echo "03:17:18 up 182 days, 12:17,  8 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.05" 
}
```

Again the point of this would be to have Blue Ocean pipeline have a stage dot with a log

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate an expression and then call it.

```
node(''){
 Closure x = evaluate("{it -> evaluate(it)}" )
 x(" stage('test'){ script { echo 'hi'}}")
}
```

Comment: evaluate is something new but how would that take external script output as its running ?

Comment: I assume, you can initialize a variable with the output of your script and then invoke the closure.

Comment: I guess i need a bit more help on this. The python (or other) script is running on server and needs to send status to jenkins when it completes a step. It then should be able to inject that as a step in the pipeline and continue on to another task then update that as a new step. So how does that happen with evaluate ?

Answer (score 1):

Since Jenkins converts your Groovy script into Java, compiles it and *then* executes the result, it would be quite hard to use an external program to generate more Groovy to execute, since that additional groovy code would need to be converted. But the generated code is a result of running, which means that the conversion is already done.

Instead, you may want to programmatically build your stages in Groovy.

```
some_array = ["/tmp/demo.py", "sleep 10", "uptime"] 

def getBuilders()
{
    def builders = [:]

    some_array.eachWithIndex { it, index ->
        // name the stage
        def name = 'Stage #' + (index + 1)
        builders[name] = {
            stage (name) {
                def my_label = "jenkins_label" // can choose programmatically if needed
                node(my_label) {
                        try {
                            doSomething(it)
                        }
                        catch (err) { println "Failed to run ${it}"; throw err  }
                        finally {  }
                    }
            }
        }
    };
    return builders
}

def doSomething(something) {
    sh "${something}"
}
```

And later in your main pipeline

```
        stage('Do it all') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def builders = getBuilders()
                    parallel builders
                }
            }
```

This will run three parallel stages, where one would be running `/tmp/demo.py`, the second `sleep 10`, and the third `uptime`.

Comment: Your example is interesting but it could only work if it opened a pipe to the external script. So if the doSomething where to create a stage as it got a message from the pipe.  Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question.What 'pipe' are you talking about?

Comment: You can envoke external program and read its output with `def to_do = sh (script: "1.sh", returnStdout: true).trim()` and later pass it as `doSomething(to_do)`. So if there's `echo sleep 90` inside `1.sh`, this will be passed and later invoked.